# Flexdashboard: Multiple pages, multiple orientations (rows v. columns)

Tags: r, r-markdown, orientation, flexdashboard

I'm relatively new to using Flexdashboard in Rmarkdown.

**My goal: have page 1 be oriented as rows and a second page be oriented as columns.**

Page 1 layout as rows:

[image]

Page 2 layout as columns:

[image]

**I've researched:**
These two posts with no luck:
[Flexdashboard multiple attributes page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47712019/flexdashboard-multiple-attributes-page)
[Combine in flexdashboard with multiple pages different types of vertical_layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43225165/combine-in-flexdashboard-with-multiple-pages-different-types-of-vertical-layout)

Also couldn't find anything in the helpful Rmarkdown guide: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/layout.html

**I tried**
a couple different versions of overriding the global orientation in my page header, to no avail. For example (which doesn't work):

```
Page 2 as columns {data-icon="fa-signal" orientation: columns}
=====
```

**A sample code:**

````
---
title: example
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    vertical_layout: fill
---
---

Page 1 as Rows
=====

Column {data-width=450}
------

### Vis 1

```{r}
plot(iris)
```


column {data-width=450}
------

### Plot 1

```{r}
knitr::kable(mtcars)
```

### Plot2

```{r}
plot(mtcars)
```



Page 2 as columns {data-icon="fa-signal" orientation: columns} #this doesn't work but want dif layout here
=====

Column {data-width=450}
------

### Vis 1

```{r}
plot(iris)
```


column {data-width=450}
------

### Plot 1

```{r}
knitr::kable(mtcars)
```

### Plot2

```{r}
plot(mtcars)
```
````

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

First, set orientation to columns by deleting "orientation: rows"

```
---
title: example
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    vertical_layout: fill
---
```

then for every subsequent page that you want to set as row, just add {data-orientation=rows}

```
Page 1 as Rows {data-orientation=rows}
=====
```